# No handler was subscribed to command. Axon 3.3

Tags: spring-boot, cqrs, axon

I'm attempting to create basic Axon/Spring application by tutorial, but faced with strange error like: NoHandlerForCommandException: No handler was subscribed to command. It seems that Axon can't see @CommandHandler annotation.

Here my files:

aggregate

```
@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private UUID accountId;
    private Double balance;

    @CommandHandler
    public Account(CreateAccountCommand command) {
        apply(new AccountCreatedEvent(command.getAccountId(), command.getName()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(AccountCreatedEvent event) {
        this.accountId = event.getAccountId();
        this.balance = 0.0;
    } 
}
```

event

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class AccountCreatedEvent {

    private UUID accountId;
    private String name;
}
```

command

```
@Getter
public class CreateAccountCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private UUID accountId;
    private String name;

    public CreateAccountCommand(UUID accountId, String name) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

spring boot conf

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public EventStorageEngine inMemoryEventStorageEngine() {
            return new InMemoryEventStorageEngine();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

this is how i send cmd

```
@Component
public class AppLoader {

    @Autowired
    private CommandGateway cmdGateway;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cmdGateway.send(new CreateAccountCommand(UUID.randomUUID(), "test"));
    }
}
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'io.yourpoint.nettnews'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon-test', version: '3.3.5'
    compile group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon-spring-boot-starter', version: '3.3.5'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that performing the `CommandGateway#send()` call in a `@PostConstruct` is to early for Axon..

As it currently stands, all the command, event and query handlers typically get registered *after* all your beans have been initialized.
Moving the `CommandGateway#send()` behind a REST endpoint should give you a big enough time frame to ensure all the handlers have been registered.

So in short, it's a timing issues why you get the `NoHandlerForCommandException`.

We (at AxonIQ) see benefit in sending some sort of application events as soon as all the handlers have been registered. That's a thing for the future though.

Hope this helps you out @Benjamin!

Comment: Any updates on the application events? I run into a similar situation.

Comment: It's pending for 4.6.0, which is the upcoming minor release of AF. I'd wager we should be able to get it resolved, although I'm not making any promises on this. If you're interested, you can find the issue in question here, tbeernot: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/880